# Best practice for formatting text from database in JS - SQL environment?

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I have a column in database with some text. I need to show this on a web page with some HTML formatting - say, I need to have a line break between two sentences in the text. What is the best way to implement this?

A couple of ways:
 1. Have the HTML in the database table
 2. Have the second sentence in a separate column and perform the formatting on the UI

What would be the best way to do this? One thing to note is that, the formatting for this data is dynamic . I.E sometimes I need to have a line break b/w the sentences, other times I need hyperlinks added to some work in a sentence etc.

Comment: How does the text get into the database to start with?

Comment: It is updated by a program that runs as a recurring job.

Answer (score 0):

When the content is so specifically formatted with hyperlinks on some words, I would save the HTML in the database.

But please make sure that all the data you write into the DB is properly escaped in order to ensure the safety of your system. Check out [this Wikipedia entry about HTML sanitizion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization).

Comment: yes, I took care of that. But storing HTML in database with all the UI formatting information seems really crude.

Comment: But why not? If the text is some way formatted, you have store the formatting anyway.

Comment: it seems to violate the "Separation of concerns" paradigm